# Facebook dynamic URL troubles

Tags: facebook, url, dynamic, analytics, utm-tracking

I have some troubles with facebook dynamic URL
I'm using this part of code at facebook ad: 
utm_source={{site_source_name}}&utm_medium={{campaign.id}}&utm_campaign={{adset.id}}&utm_term={{ad.id}}&utm_content={{placement}}

But , in my browser and GA I see next: badidname, badcampaign name...

Can you help me?

Comment: That’s a bad question title, and the question text doesn’t make it clear what your actual issue is either. Please go read [ask], and edit accordingly.

Comment: We've had this same issue in my workplace. As far as we can tell, the dynamic URL parameters never worked, and all documentation relating to the feature has been removed. Also talking to their support team, they deny any knowledge of the feature. I'd say it was silently rolled back. Would love to know anyone elses info on the issue.